# Lie bracket as a measure of the failure of matrices to commute?

Tags: matrices, differential-geometry

In section 10.4.2 of the book *Differential Geometry* by Taubes, the author asserts that Lie bracket is a measure of the failure of matrices to commute: if $A$, $B$ are real or complex $n\times n$ matrices, we have
$$e^Ae^Be^{-A}e^{-B}=I_n+AB-BA+e,$$
where $e$ has the norm of order $|A||B|(|A|+|B|)$. I got stuck in here cause I couldn't figure out why $e$ has the norm. I tried Taylor expansion but still couldn't see why.

Comment: What you've written out is _exactly_ the Taylor expansion of $e^Ae^Be^{-A}e^{-B}$, up to second degree. That means that the error term $e$ must have whatever's left, which starts at degree $3$ and contains terms like $ABB$ and $ABA$.

Comment: @Arthur But there are infinitely many terms left. I cannot show that the sum is of the norm.

Comment: If the norm of $A$ and $B$ are large, then yes, you cannot discard the higher degree terms. I would assume $|A|$ and $|B|$ are both at most around $1$ if the author makes a simplification like that.

Comment: @Arthur I see what you mean! I shall go check it.